# Background music should duck (pause) on playing video

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-video

**Background Music from other apps should stops while playing video in react native app.**

Using "react-native-video": *"git://github.com/olofd/react-native-video.git#react-native-photos-framework"*

I am stuck, please respond as soon as possible.

Comment: can you share your codes i will help you

Comment: @AmirDoreh

<Video source={{ uri: 'Video URL' }}
                                 paused={false}
                                 ref={r => (this.vid = r)}
                                 muted={false}
                                 repeat
                                 onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
                                 resizeMode='cover'
                                 />

Please Help!!

Comment: @PranavSharma did you find any solution?